# Adjective ending -e with the noun Möbel

Tags: grammatical-case

Normally the adjective ending for "nullartikel" takes the ending that the definite article would have taken, had there been one. For instance:

> Ich esse gern frisches Brot.

Recently I saw this sentence:

> Suche antike Möbel.

My question is this: Möbel is "das Möbel", even when refering to several pieces of furniture. So why isn't the correct adjective "antikes" in the above sentence?

Comment: First of all it's "Möbel". Why would "das Möbel" stay "das Möbel" in plural? German has a plural article, so several pieces would be "die Möbel".

Comment: I corrected my spelling mistake.

Comment: As an aside: "das Möbel" does indeedcdenote a single piece of furniture, but it's not usually used. The plural form of "Möbel" is typically used for indefinite amounts of furniture; as soon as you count them, you use "Möbelstück".

Answer (score 6):

You wrote:

> Möbel is "das Möbel", even when refering to several pieces of furniture.

This is not correct. [*Das Möbel*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/M%C3%B6bel) refers to one piece of furniture only. Referring to many pieces requires the plural *die Möbel*.

The four cases of the plural phrase *antike Möbel* are:

- nominative: antike Möbel
- genitive: antiker Möbel
- dative: antiken Möbeln
- accusative: antike Möbel

In the phrase

> Suche antike Möbel.

the accusative plural is used.

Comment: I doubt *Das Möbel* should refer to anything. *Die Möbel* appears always in the plural, and thus as a pluraletantum (like *the police* (never *?a police* but *a policeman*). The count noun in my regiolect is *Möbelstück*, which is no less jaring, or anything else. Maybe that's different in your neck of the woods, or your favorite dictionary.

Comment: Fortunately, it is absolutely irrelevant what @vectory (once again) doubts or believes! https://www.dwds.de/wb/M%C3%B6bel

Comment: I have never before doubted that *das Möbel* were acceptable. I saw it for the first time, and if there's hope also for the last time, today

Comment: "Bedeutungen: [1] Singular ungebräuchlich: großer Einrichtungsgegenstand" https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bel

Comment: @vectory: I find your quote `I doubt Das Möbel should refer to anything.` very clear that there is your doubt about the "legality"/ existance of the singular "Das Möbel."

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich a single piece clearly doesn't need a collective noun denoting it. Vice versa, you can surely find degenerate examples of singular use for Polizei or Eltern (vgl. auch Schweiz *Möbeln* zur n-stämmigen Bildungsform), and cetera (not saying I could, didn't even try), but those are funny at least

Comment: "der Singular ist jedoch bis in die Gegenwart wenig gebräuchlich (dafür Möbelstück, 19. Jh.)." sag ich doch; ist dir sicherlich auch nicht neu. So zu tun als wäre es dir neu und eine bodenlose Unterstellung ist eigentlich eine bodenlose Unterstellung. "Hierauf beruht die vom frühen 17. Jh. an belegte Entlehnung Meubles ‘Hausrat’, seit dem 18. Jh. ‘Einrichtungsgegenstände’, die durch Austausch der Pluralendung (Meublen, 1688) und Umlautschreibung (Möbeln, 18. Jh.; Möbel, 19. Jh.) zunehmend eingedeutscht wird", merke: ursprünglich plural, bzwbunzählbar, wie *Rat*

Comment: "Das 18. Jh. kennt auch die Singularformen Meuble, Möble, Möbel, anfangs mit femininem, in der 2. Jahrhunderthälfte mit neutralem Genus;" ohne Ortsangabe eher wertlos

Comment: Please, stop spamming my answer!

Answer (score 4):

As a language learner, you have to be on the lookout for nouns that don't change in the plural. This mostly concerns masculine and neuter nouns ending in *-el, -en, -er*. Some examples:

> der Nebel, Spiegel, Zweifel – das Kabel, Mittel, Viertel
>   der Brunnen, Knochen, Streifen – das Eisen, Wesen, Zeichen
>   der Bürger, Koffer, Treffer – das Fenster, Lager, Zimmer

For [count nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun), the presence or absence of a determiner will help distinguish singular and plural uses. ("Nullartikel" written as ∅.)

> Das Programm findet ∅ Rechtschreibfehler. *(plural)*
>   Das Programm hat einen/den Rechtschreibfehler gefunden. *(singular)*

Unfortunately, in newspaper ads, articles are optional even for count nouns.  But singular and plural can still be distinguished by the adjective ending. The rule you gave for the ending of the adjective is correct.

> Suche ∅ antik**es** Möbel. (*singular*, -es *as in* das, welches, *etc.*)
>   Suche ∅ antik**e** Möbel. (*plural*, -e *as in* die, keine, *etc.*)

Finally, note that many speakers prefer to use *Möbel* in the plural only; *Möbelstück* is used for a piece of furniture.